# Kotlin: Line continuation in multiline string?

Tags: kotlin, multiline

```kotlin
val myQuestion = """
I am creating a multiline string containing paragraphs of text.  The text will wrap when put into a TextView.  

But as you can see, when defining the text in the editor, if I want to avoid newlines mid-paragraph, I need to write really long lines that require a lot of horizontal scrolling.

Is there some way that I can have line breaks in the editor that don't appear in the actual value of the string?
"""
```

Comment: Write `"first line" + "second line" + "third line"` instead of using the multiline string literal. Then you can separate each line in the source code without actually having newlines in the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach is to treat a **single-newline** as an "editor only" newline, which gets removed.  If you actually want a single-newline put a double-newline.  If you want a double, put a triple, and so-on:

```
val INFO_TEXT = """
    I am creating a multiline string containing paragraphs of text.  
    The text will wrap when put into a TextView.  


    But as you can see, when defining the text in the editor, 
    if I want to avoid newlines mid-paragraph, I need to write 
    really long lines that require a lot of horizontal scrolling.


    Is there some way that I can have line breaks in the editor 
    that don't appear in the actual value of the string?
""".trimIndent().replace(Regex("(\n*)\n"), "$1")
```

This is similar to the approach of Markdown - which ignores lone newlines (unless the previous line ends with 2 or more spaces - which I find confusing).

Answer (score 9):

Inspired by how you can add `$` in a multiline string (which you otherwise cannot do) by doing `${"$"}`, I've thought of this way of adding a line break in the multiline string literal, but not in the string value itself.

```
val myQuestion = """
    I am creating a multiline string containing paragraphs of text.  ${""
    }The text will wrap when put into a TextView.  

    But as you can see, when defining the text in the editor, ${""
    }if I want to avoid newlines mid-paragraph, I need to write ${""
    }really long lines that require a lot of horizontal scrolling.

    Is there some way that I can have line breaks in the editor ${""
    }that don't appear in the actual value of the string?
""".trimIndent()
```

(The indentation and `trimIndent` are just there to make it look nice. They are not required for this to work.)

Basically, I'm exploiting the fact that you can put arbitrary whitespace in `${ ... }`, so how about putting a line break there? There still gotta be an expression in `${ ... }` though, so you have to write `""` to append *nothing* to the string.

Comment: Creative!,  I like it.  Too bad kotlin lacks a line continuation character.

Comment: I'm considering it...